# Logarithmic properties to expand $\ln\left(2b \sqrt\frac{b+1}{b-1}\right)$.

Tags: logarithms

I am having a hard time with logarithmic properties, and I was wondering how to expand this equation by using the properties.  The equation and the steps I have done so far are $$\ln\left(2b \sqrt\frac{b+1}{b-1}\right)$$  $$\text{Quotient rule:}\phantom2 \ln(2b\sqrt{b+1})-\ln(\sqrt{b-1})$$ $$ \text{Exponent rule:} \phantom2 \frac12\ln(2b(b+1))-\frac12\ln(2b(b-1))$$

Is this right so far?  Is this what you would do to expand this equation by using logarithmic properties?

thanks

Comment: A mental trick to handle problems like this is to write the argument as a product of $z^k$ terms; each such term becomes a sum-term $k\ln z$.

Comment: What you did with the "exponent rule" is incorrect: $$
\frac{1}{2}\ln (2b(b + 1)) - \frac{1}{2}\ln (2b(b - 1)) = \ln \left( {\frac{{\sqrt {2b(b + 1)} }}{{\sqrt {2b(b - 1)} }}} \right) = \ln \left( {\sqrt {\frac{{b + 1}}{{b - 1}}} } \right) \ne \ln \left( {2b\sqrt {\frac{{b + 1}}{{b - 1}}} } \right).
$$

Comment: More generally, you can write$$\ln\left(x\sqrt{y/z}\right)=\tfrac12\ln(x^2yz)=\ln x+\tfrac12\ln y-\tfrac12\ln z$$or$$\ln\left(x\sqrt{y/z}\right)=\ln x+\ln\sqrt{y/z}=\ln x+\tfrac12\ln y-\tfrac12\ln z.$$Your quotient rule worked, but your exponent rule was incorrect; it reduced to $\tfrac12\ln y-\tfrac12\ln z$.

Answer (score 1):

Your exponent rule is incorrectly applied: $\ln(2b \sqrt{b + 1}) ≠ \frac{1}{2}\ln(2b(b + 1))$. Instead, $\frac{1}{2}\ln(2b(b + 1)) = \ln(\sqrt{(2b(b + 1))})$. Note how the root applies to entire function inside.

$$\to \ln(2b \sqrt{b+1}) - \ln(\sqrt{b-1})$$
$$\to \ln(2b) + \ln(\sqrt{b+1}) - \ln(\sqrt{b-1})$$
$$\to \ln(2b) + \frac{1}{2}(\ln(\frac{b + 1}{b-1}))$$
$$\to \ln(2b) + \frac{1}{2}\ln(1+\frac{2}{b-1})$$

You may be able to expand further. Also logarithmics are funny when it comes to domain and functions. Watch out and check that domain matches to your **initial** given function, in every step when working with logarithms, as you might introduce extra solutions from rationalising denominators to separating logs.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I worked my way through most of the problem.  $ln(2b\sqrt\frac{b+1}{b-1})$  $$ln(2)+ln(b)+\frac12ln(b+1)-\frac12ln(b_1)$$ $$ln(2)+ln(b)+\frac{(b+1)-(b-1)}{2}$$

Comment: The last line is to read: $$ln(2)+ln(b)+\frac{ln(b+1)-ln(b-1}{2}$$,  I did still have a question about why the $ln(b+1)-ln(b-1)$ are put over 2.  Is it safe to say since both the terms $ln(b+1)$ and $ln(b-1)$ are being multiplied by 1/2 and that is the reason why they two terms are put into the numerator?

Comment: @Benp404 yes both of them are being multiplied by 1/2. Since the terms are also being subtracted, you can simplify it in one fraction, by putting it over 2 (since its half). $$\frac{1}{2} \times \ln{(b + 1)} = \frac{\ln{(b + 1)}}{2}$$ Similarly, applying it to both at once becomes $$\frac{\ln{(b + 1)}}{2} - \frac{\ln{(b + 1)}}{2}$$. You can combine both numerators just like you did after this step if you want just 1 fraction.

Comment: I think the domain is b>1.

Comment: In the previous comment the $-\frac{\ln(b+1)}{2}$ should be $-\frac{\ln(b - 1)}{2}$. Sorry about that. Indeed the domain is $b > 1$.